# Qt Quick does not translate components loaded via Loader

Tags: qt, internationalization, qml

Situation:

Writing a Qt Quick application for embedded Linux system, want to use Qt translation mechnanism. Application shall select language on command coming in via RS232, currently hardcoded to "de" on a system set up for english language. Application loads various masks on command from RS232.

Problem:

Qt Quick translates only the main page (main.qml), but not the pages loaded via the Qt Loader (DEMO.ui.qml). Texts from main.qml are displayed in german, texts from DEMO.ui.qml are displayed untranslated.

I've added a "XX" prefix to all english translations (qml.en.ts), that also does not appear on the screen. So neither english nor german translations are loaded for pages loaded via the Qt Loader.

Clean build after lupdate, lrelease does not help. rm -rf build-$appname-*, build does not help.

Code:

application.cpp:

```
xlat=new QTranslator();
if (xlat->load(QLocale("de"), "qml", ".", ":/qml/i18n/", ".qm")) {
    qDebug()<<"load translator ok";
    bool ok=installTranslator(xlat);
    //...
} // else error message
// ...
viewer->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
viewer->showFullScreen();
// ...
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    Text {
        id: loadingMsg
        text: qsTr("Loading ...")
        // ...
    }
    Loader {
        // ...
        source: ""
        function loadMask(aMaskId) {
            // ...
            setSource(gui.urlForMask(aMaskId));
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

components/SimpleButton.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
// ...
Rectangle {
    Text { 
        id: label
        text: ""
        // ...
    }
    property alias text: label.text
}
```

masks/DEMO.ui.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "../components"
//...
    SimpleButton {
        //...
        text: qsTr("Vent.")
    }
//...
```

qml.de.ts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="de_DE">
<!-- ... -->
<context>
    <name>DEMO</name>
    <!-- ... --->
    <message>
        <source>Vent.</source>
        <translation>Belüften</translation>
    </message>
</context>
<context>
    <name>main</name>
    <message>
        <source>Loading ...</source>
        <translation>Lade ...</translation>
    </message>
    <!-- ... -->
</context>
```

Comment: Is `DEMO.ui.qml` listed in the `SOURCES` variable as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html#use-a-conditional-to-hide-qml-source-from-the-compiler)?

Comment: yes: `lupdate_only { SOURCES += qml/*.qml qml/masks/*.qml }`

Answer (score 1):

Renaming `DEMO.ui.qml` to `DEMO.qml` did the trick. I guess that the Linguist tools (`lupdate`, `lrelease`) and the Qt runtime environment have different ideas of how to convert a filename to a context name.